# How i put my App on top of Accessibility Permission List Android OS?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

[image]

Hey Guys!
I'm building an app that uses accessibility permission, i ask user on runtime to give this permission as per Android Developers guidelines.
But my app is shown always at the bottom of the list of Accessibility Permision Settings Screen, refer screenshot my app is "MyAccessibilityService" while other apps like Jugnoo , Makhichoose .. always appear on top even if i uninsatll them and install my app at 1st then install them again, i tried all iterations result is same . So there's some thing else how android OS is managing this list, means how it is sorting it??
How can i make my app appear on top ?
Pls Help.

Comment: What device/version of Android are you using?  Let's say you did get this working on this version of Android.  It could be completely different on another.  Why worry about things you have little to no control over?  You could write your own launcher app, with your own settings mechanism if you really care that much...

Comment: When it comes to ease of access for users it matters,.BTW. im using Android 6.0

Comment: I understand the benefits.  However, "ease of access for users" is somewhat arbitrary and opinionated.

Comment: Priority is the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Add `priority` to intent filter:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="99">
    <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: The highest priority possible is 999. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a phone book, and you were use to the ordering of that phone book.  Would forcing "John Smith" to appear between "AAA, AAAA" and "AAA, AAAB" really be easier to access?  The phone book creator obviously would not do this.  Your service is your service.  The settings app controls where your service goes in that list.  End of story.

On my device it appears to be installation order, oldest last.  The only way you can get your service to show up on the top of that list, would be to have users uninstall all of their services, install yours, and then reinstall all of their services again.  There's nothing saying in future releases this will remain that way, or that your device could be different.

Comment: "The only way you can get your service to show up on the top of that list, would be to have users uninstall all of their services, install yours, and then reinstall all of their services again." - That's not correct. Voodoo is able to get it on top every time. No matter if it is installed first or last.

Comment: "On my device"... "There's nothing saying in future releases this will remain that way, or that your device could be different."

Comment: "The settings app controls where your service goes in that list. End of story."